# R / quantmod - discrepancy between BBands() and runsd(EMA) calculations

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to create a signal state when my spread calculation is greater than or less than upper/lower Bollinger Bands, however my calculations:

```
pair <- c("qqq","iwm")
start <-  "2014-08-08"
finish <- "2015-08-13"
stckY <- suppressWarnings(getSymbols(pair[1], from = start, to = finish, auto.assign = FALSE))
stckX <- suppressWarnings(getSymbols(pair[2], from = start, to = finish, auto.assign = FALSE))

adY <- Ad(stckY)
adX <- Ad(stckX)

logY <- log(adY)
logX <- log(adX)

spread <- cbind(logY, logX)
spread <- spread[complete.cases(spread),] #remove NAs
spread$dailyDiff <- spread[,1] - spread[,2]

ema <- EMA(spread[,1] - spread[,2], n=20)
spread$UpBand <- (runSD(ema, n=20) * 2) + ema
spread$LwBand <- ema - (runSD(ema, n=20) * 2)

chartSeries(spread$dailyDiff, up.col = "white", 
            theme = chartTheme("black"), line.type = "l")
addEMA(n = 20, col = "orange")
addBBands(n = 20, sd = 2, maType = "EMA")
```

aren't matching the band values displayed on the chartSeries display and I cannot figure out why? The help file states that not using SMA might cause "inconsistencies", so maybe this is the source of the problem? The chartSeries is also using an EMA.

Perhaps there is a better way to go about this? I'm not sure how to reference the upper/lower bands using BBands() alone...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're comparing and how they're different. A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616) would be a lot better than a vague description.

Comment: The code in your comments is very hard to read. Please edit it into your question (with proper code formatting) and then delete your comments.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - sorry about that - still learning this site - I've updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. You're taking the standard deviation of the moving average when you should be taking the standard deviation of the original series.
2. The `BBands` function uses `sample = FALSE` in the `runSD` call.

This replicates the output of the `BBands` function in your chart:

```
ema <- EMA(spread$dailyDiff, n=20)
spread$UpBand <- runSD(spread$dailyDiff, n=20, sample=FALSE) * 2 + ema
spread$LwBand <- ema - runSD(spread$dailyDiff, n=20, sample=FALSE) * 2
tail(spread)
#            QQQ.Adjusted IWM.Adjusted   dailyDiff      UpBand     LwBand
# 2015-08-06     4.704563     4.793060 -0.08849663 -0.06442705 -0.1381200
# 2015-08-07     4.703295     4.786575 -0.08328008 -0.06687188 -0.1322478
# 2015-08-10     4.714652     4.798267 -0.08361464 -0.06938022 -0.1267023
# 2015-08-11     4.701752     4.789323 -0.08757113 -0.07421110 -0.1198771
# 2015-08-12     4.705196     4.787408 -0.08221192 -0.07856667 -0.1126964
# 2015-08-13     4.703566     4.784320 -0.08075361 -0.08283161 -0.1055975
tail(BBands(spread$dailyDiff, n=20, maType="EMA"))
#                    dn        mavg          up      pctB
# 2015-08-06 -0.1381200 -0.10127351 -0.06442705 0.6733800
# 2015-08-07 -0.1322478 -0.09955985 -0.06687188 0.7490178
# 2015-08-10 -0.1267023 -0.09804126 -0.06938022 0.7516764
# 2015-08-11 -0.1198771 -0.09704411 -0.07421110 0.7074403
# 2015-08-12 -0.1126964 -0.09563152 -0.07856667 0.8931942
# 2015-08-13 -0.1055975 -0.09421457 -0.08283161 1.0912769
```

Comment: bingo, thanks - you've been very helpful, much appreciated